# How to get the first quartile value in a set of values in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of average scores in the table and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the value of the cell that I need to get.

I have a quartile computation that divides the data into four (Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4). I already figured out the formula to get the first quartile (57.65-65.90).

[image: insert picture]

These are sample data. I need to get the first value of Q2 but I can't figure out the formula to do so.

[image: insert picture]

I tried to get it manually by just referring to the cell, but as soon as I put new data, it simply will not be applicable. I want it to be automated so that all new data will be computed automatically.

Comment: So is the result you want with sample data just 66.45? This could change as more data are added, but is always the lowest value greater than 65.9?

Comment: Yes @TomSharpe. I want to get the lowest value of each quartile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to find the lowest value in the second group of numbers. Assuming the the data are sorted in descending order and that you know the group sizes in advance (16, 16, 15 and 14) this would be given by:

```
=INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)-C3)&"-"&E1
```

For the third and fourth group you would need to find the value before the last 32 and 47 values respectively i.e. you would need to add up the previous group sizes:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COUNT($A:$A)-SUM($C3:E3*ISODD(COLUMN($C3:E3)))&"-"&G1)
```

You could also find the position of the required value by matching:

```
=INDEX(A:A,XMATCH(C1,A:A)-1)&"-"&E1
```

but I think it isn't as reliable because it could go wrong if there were duplicate values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With this formula in D4 cell:

`=TOROW(HSTACK(FREQUENCY(A1:A17,{65.9,68.65,70.85,77.45}),FREQUENCY(A1:A17,{65.9,68.65,70.85,77.45})/SUM(FREQUENCY(A1:A17,{65.9,68.65,70.85,77.45}))))`

you can get this result:

[image]

If you don't need the over the last range data then the formula

`=DROP(TOROW(HSTACK(FREQUENCY(A1:A17,{65.9,68.65,70.85,77.45}),FREQUENCY(A1:A17,{65.9,68.65,70.85,77.45})/SUM(FREQUENCY(A1:A17,{65.9,68.65,70.85,77.45})))),,-2)`